# NodeJS / Mongoose add Subdocument and update total price and quantity

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm trying to add a subdocument and also update the `"total"` and `"quanity"` fields of the main document.  Right now, I'm doing it like this, but this seems really ugly and inefficient.  Is there a better way to achieve this?

```
// Adds subdocument    
const cart = await Cart.findByIdAndUpdate({_id: req.session.cart._id}, {$push: {courses: req.body}}, {new:true})

// Update totals and quantity   
cart.set({total: cart.total + parseInt(req.body.price), quantity: cart.quantity + 1})
await cart.save()
```

Ideally I would want something like this (the below clearly doesn't work but it's what I'm aiming for logically):

```
const cart = await Cart.findByIdAndUpdate(req.session.cart._id, async function(err, doc){
    if(err){
        res.status(404).json({error:err.message})    
    } else{
        doc.courses.push(req.body.course)
        doc.total = doc.total + parseInt(req.body.price)
        doc.quantity = doc.quantity + 1
        await doc.save()
       
    }
}, {new: true})
```

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$inc` operator to atomic update one document

refer to [$inc operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/v5.0/reference/operator/update/inc/#mongodb-update-up.-inc):

> The $inc operator increments a field by a specified value

Your operation could be something like:

```js
const cart = await Cart.findByIdAndUpdate(
  {_id: req.session.cart._id}, 
  {
    $push: {courses: req.body},
    $inc: {
      total: parseInt(req.body.price),
      quantity: 1,
    },
  }, 
  {new:true}
)
```

Comment: Thank you! :) This is what I'm looking for.